# Make composer use my "forked" project in my private repository, not the "official" project

Tags: php, laravel, git, composer-php

Composer version 2.4.4

The official/upstream repository for laravel-menus is here: https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-menus.git

If my downstream copy is here (here's a slightly changed URL): git@gitlab.mydomain.com:myteam/laravel-menus.git

The myteam/laravel package (the main project/root) has this in composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
       "type": "vcs",
       "url": "git@gitlab.mydomain.edu:myteam/laravel-lib.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "myteam/laravel-lib": "^1.0"
},
```

myteam/laravel references myteam/laravel-lib, which has this in composer.json:

```
   "repositories": [
        {
           "type": "vcs",
           "url": "git@gitlab.mydomain.edu:myteam/laravel-menus.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "nwidart/laravel-menus": "dev-myteam-fixes"
    },
```

In summary, A) myteam/laravel references B) myteam/laravel-lib and B) myteam/laravel-lib references C) nwidart/laravel-menus (dev-myteam-fixes branch) which is our private branch.

Composer is ignoring the repository configuration in B) myteam/laravel-lib, not getting code from my private repository, and instead getting code from https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-menus.git (the upstream repository)

Comment: I don't see how what you're asking is anything other than "How to use a specific tag/version with composer and a private git repository" You have your own repository you want it to use? And a particular version from that repository?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Honestly, I care less about the specific version and more about how to make it even get any code in my repository.  No tag I've tried helps.

Comment: instead of composer update, try to use composer install.

Comment: try to change the composer.lock instead.

Comment: If it still does not work, undo the composer.json to use the original `url` of the package. next remove the package with `composer remove ...` next install `your` package from your repo using `composer require git-name/package-name`.

Comment: added more details to my question

Comment: not sure why people are voting down the question

Comment: I can see you said you removed the composer.lock.. Did you try what my 2nd recommendation instead? Undo all/any changes to composer.json and lock file. next remove the package with `composer remove ...` next install your package from your repo using `composer require git-name/package-name`

Comment: Using the commands above, it will remove the composer package (original repo) then install `your` forked repo. Note: when doing composer remove, it may also remove dependency packages but it should be re installed again once you do composer require. When they are reinstalled, some of the dependency package **may** install the corresponding latest version.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth  That did not work, unfortunately.  Note that both the forked version and the upstream version are the same except for a couple of fixes.  they both have the name nwidart/laravel-menus.

Comment: If you `forked` the repo, shouldn't it be in `your-git-name/forked-repo`?

Comment: Maybe I did not specify. `composer require your-git-name/forked-repo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting if it helps anyone in the future

From: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#i-have-a-dependency-which-contains-a-repositories-definition-in-its-composer-json-but-it-seems-to-be-ignored-

Docs say:

> The repositories configuration property is defined as root-only. It is
> not inherited. You can read more about the reasons behind this in the
> "why can't Composer load repositories recursively?" article. The
> simplest work-around to this limitation, is moving or duplicating the
> repositories definition into your root composer.json.

So, ignoring repository definitions that are not in the root composer.json is a feature, not a bug.